# How to show a picture with a transparent background (like png) when the app loads in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

One example is photoshop, when the application starts up, a really nice picture with a transparent background shows up. how can I achieve the same result while building my own application? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You mean a splash screen?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering how to get a custom-shaed window, rather than simply how to display it at launch, the [RoundTransparentWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) example code provided by Apple shows how you can achieve this.